# angular material nav bar not opening the menus

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am working on an angular project in which after login I need to show the menu to user which should be collapsable . here is my code for material nav bar but its not opening the menus list when I click on it .

```
    <mat-toolbar color="primary">
        <button mat-icon-button (click)="toggleCollapse()">
          <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
        </button>
        <span class="app-title">

 Dashboard</span>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <button mat-raised-button color="warn" (click)="logout()">Logout</button>
  </mat-toolbar>
  
  <mat-sidenav-container>
    <mat-sidenav [mode]="isCollapsed ? 'over' : 'side'" [opened]="!isCollapsed">
      <mat-nav-list>
        <a mat-list-item routerLink="/dashboard" routerLinkActive="active-link">
          <mat-icon>dashboard</mat-icon>
          <span>Dashboard</span>
        </a>
        <a mat-list-item routerLink="/details" routerLinkActive="active-link">
          <mat-icon>info</mat-icon>
          <span>Details</span>
        </a>
        <a mat-list-item routerLink="/users" routerLinkActive="active-link">
          <mat-icon>group</mat-icon>
          <span>Users</span>
        </a>
        <a mat-list-item routerLink="/change-password" routerLinkActive="active-link">
          <mat-icon>lock</mat-icon>
          <span>Change Password</span>
        </a>
      </mat-nav-list>
    </mat-sidenav>
  
    <mat-sidenav-content>
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </mat-sidenav-content>
  </mat-sidenav-container>
```

and .ts file as follow :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-nav-bar',
  templateUrl: './nav-bar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nav-bar.component.css']
})
export class NavBarComponent {
  isCollapsed = true;
  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) { }
  toggleCollapse(): void {
    alert("Hi");
   
    this.isCollapsed = !this.isCollapsed;
    
  }

  logout(): void { 
   
    localStorage.removeItem('token');
    this.authService.logout();
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  }
}
```

I am using this nav bar in master component as follow :

```
<app-nav-bar></app-nav-bar>
<div class="content">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
<style>
  .content {
    padding: 20px;
  }
</style>
```

and for nav bar component css is as follow :

```
.mat-sidenav {
    width: 250px;
  }
  
  .app-title {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
  
  .spacer {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
  }

  .container {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
  }
  
  mat-sidenav-container {
    flex: 1;
  }
```

just to insure everone understands what packages I am using so I am putting package.json file as well.

```
{
  "name": "pay-ui",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~14.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "~14.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~14.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~14.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~14.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~14.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~14.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~14.0.0",
    "chart.js": "^4.3.0",
    "ng2-charts": "^4.1.1",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.2.11",
    "@angular/cli": "~14.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~14.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.10.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.6.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing a stackblitz snippet?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-3fhopr?file=app%2Fnav-bar.component.ts

Comment: Is there a reason to use `Angular 4` and `Material 2` ?

Comment: No , there is no reason to use any specific version for material.

Answer (score 1):

As per your code, You need to wrap a `div` for `ng-content` and you can project your content in `<app-nav-bar>projected content</app-nav-bar>`. Here is the working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/simple-angular-mat-table-example-ucyuzp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) snippet.

```
 <mat-sidenav-content>
    <div class="container">
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
```

This would be the ideal solution using `router-outlet` for components rounting [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/simple-angular-mat-table-example-6s4scf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.scss,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fstyles.scss,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp-routing.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fdetails%2Fdetails.component.html)